# Room select expression

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components

I need to create a not so simple Sql select query.

Something like this:

```
 @Query("$SELECT_FROM  $PRODUCT_TRANSACTION_TABLE WHERE write_status == ($SALE || $AUDIT)")
    fun loadProductSaleTransactions(): LiveData<List<TransactionProductTable>>
```

the field can be `Sale` or `Audit

But room return nothing.
Can you help me to write correctly ?

Comment: you seem to be using a lot of constants, can you share their values as well?

Comment: Expand your SQL statement and try it by hand in a SQLite tool like DB Browser with a copy of your database.

Comment: @CommonsWare will try, thanks for tool suguestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing the query to:

```
 @Query("$SELECT_FROM  $PRODUCT_TRANSACTION_TABLE WHERE write_status IN ($SALE, $AUDIT)")
    fun loadProductSaleTransactions(): LiveData<List<TransactionProductTable>>
```

Let me know if this fixes the issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

just change after WHERE clause like below

```
@Query(
"$SELECT_FROM  $PRODUCT_TRANSACTION_TABLE WHERE
 write_status = $SALE OR write_status =  $AUDIT"
) fun loadProductSaleTransactions(): LiveData<List<TransactionProductTable>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("$SELECT_FROM  $PRODUCT_TRANSACTION_TABLE WHERE write_status IN ($SALE, $AUDIT)")fun loadProductSaleTransactions(): LiveData<List<TransactionProductTable>>
```